# Creating Search & redirect to another url in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5

I have created a "SearchController" Which able to fetch data from database and show it to my desire web page. This Code works Perfely.

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
    private $request;

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        /**
         * Some values for the menu etc
         */
        $menu_items = MarketType::markets();
        //$market_type = MarketType::marketName($id);

        $this->request = $request;
        /**
         * Taking input from the search form fields
         */
        $keyword = $this->request['keyword'];
        $category = $this->request['category'];
        //dd($keyword);

        /**
         * Retrieving data from the database
         */
        $generic = Market::searchNowDuplicate($keyword,$category);
        //dd($generic);

      //  $markets = Market::find($id);



        return view('frontend.search.product')
            ->with('menu', $menu_items)
            ->with('markets', $generic);


    }
```

}

Now, I am trying to add a condition that, if I select my category as এ্যাম্বুলেন্স (ambulance) than my page will redirect to "return view('frontend.service.service')".

Here Is the code,

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
    private $request;

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        /**
         * Some values for the menu etc
         */
        $menu_items = MarketType::markets();
        //$market_type = MarketType::marketName($id);

        $this->request = $request;
        /**
         * Taking input from the search form fields
         */
        $keyword = $this->request['keyword'];
        $category = $this->request['category'];
        //dd($keyword);


        if($category  ==['এ্যাম্বুলেন্স'])
        {
            $generic = Market::searchNowDuplicate($keyword,$category);
            return view('frontend.service.service')
                ->with('menu', $menu_items)
                ->with('markets', $generic);

        }
        /**
         * Retrieving data from the database
         */
        $generic = Market::searchNowDuplicate($keyword,$category);
        //dd($generic);

      //  $markets = Market::find($id);



        return view('frontend.search.product')
            ->with('menu', $menu_items)
            ->with('markets', $generic);


    }
}
```

Bt my second code is not working, i want show page "Frontend.service.service" but it always showing my page "Frontend.product.product".

Comment: What exactly isn't working? What have you tried to fix the problem? What results did you get?

Comment: Thank Sir, you for quick replay. I want to get data From 
this section

 if($category  =="এ্যাম্বুলেন্স")


Instead i am getting result from 


return view('frontend.search.product')
            ->with('menu', $menu_items)
            ->with('markets', $generic);
        {
            $generic = Market::searchNowDuplicate($keyword,$category);
            return view('frontend.service.service')
                ->with('menu', $menu_items)
                ->with('markets', $generic);

        }

Comment: That doesn't really make sense to me. You'll have to be more descriptive in your question. Try by answering the questions in my earlier comment.

Comment: ok sir, i am editing my question.

Comment: I have edited my question, is that helpful? :)

Comment: Yup, now I sort of understand what the problem is. Have you tried using `dd` to check the contents of `$category`? Also, I'm not entirely sure you can use `==` with array literals. Maybe try and compare `$category[0]` with the string literal :)

Comment: yes, i dd creak works perfectly. But sir i am unable to understands  "try and compare $category[0] with the string literal" 

Would you please describe me. I am very new in laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing category with the id from database.

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
    private $request;

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        /**
         * Some values for the menu etc
         */
        $menu_items = MarketType::markets();
        //$market_type = MarketType::marketName($id);

        $this->request = $request;
        /**
         * Taking input from the search form fields
         */
        $keyword = $this->request['keyword'];
        $category = $this->request['category'];
        //dd($keyword);


        if( $category == 17)
        {
            $keyword = $this->request['keyword'];
            $generic = Market::searchNowDuplicate($keyword,$category);
            return view('frontend.service.service')
                ->with('menu', $menu_items)
                ->with('markets', $generic);

        }

            /**
             * Retrieving data from the database
             */
            $generic = Market::searchNowDuplicate($keyword,$category);
            //dd($generic);

            //  $markets = Market::find($id);



            return view('frontend.search.product')
                ->with('menu', $menu_items)
                ->with('markets', $generic);




    }
}
```